# howto cut json string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a problem here and no idea how to solve it...

I have a json file like this:

```
{"data":[{"kw":"48","val":"10","val2":"05"},{"kw":"49","val":"04","val2":"05"}]}
```

But I need this format:

```
[{"kw":"48","val":"10","val2":"05"},{"kw":"49","val":"04","val2":"05"}]
```

In javascript/jQuery I make an ajax request and get the json back:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  cache : "false", // DEBUG
  url : weburl,
  dataType : "json",
  contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success : function(data) {
    // Strip data?
  }
  });
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Easiest thing would be to parse the json to an object, then convert the object's "data" property back to json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
success : function (data) {
    var array = data ? data.data : null;
    // now perform the required operations with array variable.
}
```

This will return just the array, not wrapped in a object.

Comment: As this is an asynchronous call, your return value can be referenced nowhere. So it's useless, although your general idea is correct.

Comment: There is no return in asynchronous calls

Comment: Thanks! That was an easy one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: "false", // DEBUG
    url: weburl,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        var arrayYouWant = data.data; // http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Data-Data-data-Data.aspx
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to strip it, you just reference it

```
success : function(data) {
    var myArrayofObjects = data.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to really understand read about the [Member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) in Javascript, particularly the **dot notation**. JSON is a subset of Javascript and the JSON object is a Javascript object in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by archive.  Do you mean simply access the array that is associated with the data property?

The array is associated to the 'data' property in your JSON string.  I would maybe change the name of the data argument passed into the success function.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: "false", // DEBUG
    url: weburl,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(resp) {
        var yourArray = resp.data; 
        console.log(yourArray);
    }
});
```

Comment: archive = just my bad english :)